# How to reduce execution time while comparing two long 2D lists

Tags: python, algorithm, execution-time

I am trying to compare two lists with each other, and appending the results to another list.

My problem is that the execution time is too high, sometimes it comes to be around 40 seconds, depending on the size of the lists. I cannot sort the list and compare with each other, as I obtained the lists from a larger dimension list, so I need the index positions to be conserved.

The first list(List1) is a 3D list while the second list(List2) is a 2D one. So I need to compare first two dimension of List1 with First two dimension of List2, and when I get a match, I append another value into a third list made using the 3rd dimension of the List1.

I am using an i5 8th gen with 8Gb RAM and getting execution time of around 10-30 seconds with the below code.
I cannot sort the list and compare with each other, as I obtained the lists from a larger dimension list, so I need the index positions to be conserved.

This is the code which I have written:

Here `lists` is my List1 (3D array), `y` is my List2 (2D array), `damage_id` is a small list of 4-5 elements.

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()
x = 0
a = 0
n = len(damage_id)
lists_classes = [[] for _ in range(n)]

while x < len(damage_id):
    #print(x)

    for i in lists[x]:
        for j in y:
            if (i[0],i[1]) == j:
                lists_classes[x].append(class_names_list[y.index(j)])
                break

    x = x + 1

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

I would be really grateful to you guys if you could let me know of some method or hypertuning to reduce the execution time. Please note the List1 and List2 are quite long lists, List1 being of variable lengths(3D) while List2 having around hundred thousand entries.

Comment: import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

x = 0 
a = 0

n = len(damage_id)
lists_classes = [[] for _ in range(n)]

while x < len(damage_id):
    #print(x)
    for i in lists[x]:
        for j in y:
            if (i[0],i[1]) == j:
                lists_classes[x].append(class_names_list[y.index(j)])
                break
    
    
    
    
    x = x + 1


stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)

Comment: You should [edit] the code into the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Yes I was trying to, apparently there is some formatting issue :(

Comment: many variables in the code are not declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert list2 into set and then check if the first two elements from list1 is in the set or not. This should improve your performance by quite a lot.

Here is a basic implementation:

```
import random

# a big 3-D array of lists
l1 = [ 
    [
        random.choice([i for i in range(10)]), 
        random.choice([i for i in range(10, 20)]), 
        random.choice([i for i in range(20, 30)])
    ] 
    for _ in range(10_000) 
] 

# big array of 2D lists
l2 = [(random.choice([i for i in range(20)]), int(random.random() * 100) % 20) for x in range(100000)] 

s = set(l2)

# %%timeit 
for point in l1: 
    x, y, z = point 
    if (x,y) in s: 
        pass
# 1.49 ms ± 158 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Checking 100,000 items from list1 to the set of 10,000 items from list2 takes 1.49 ms.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @arunmenon If this solved your problem, you should upvote and select it as accepted answer.